# How to get the client IP

Tags: go

I'm trying to get the client's ip in go using the following syntax:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w,"Ip: %v", r.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For"))
```

However, I get the null value as a function return.

Does anyone know what might be happening, as it should return the local ip, 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Does your client or proxy sends the X-Forwarded-For header?

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: Do not know. How do I know this, Mikhail?

Comment: @RenanAngeliniFerrari well if it did, you'd be getting a result out of this.... :)

Comment: I do not use proxy, mkopriva.

Comment: @RenanAngeliniFerrari then you have nothing that is setting that header and that's the reason you're getting back an empty string. For your server to be able to get the ip address from that header first it would have to be set by something, usually a proxy, like nginx.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. But how should I proceed then to set the header and get the ip back? @mkopriva

Comment: Got it. So I can not guarantee that I'll be able to get the IP address of every client who makes a request, correct? @mkopriva

Comment: @RenanAngeliniFerrari without a proxy you can be fairly certain that the header `X-Forwarded-For` will be missing. A client that sets that header by itself might be considered suspicious. Just think about what "forwarded for" means, it makes sense for a proxy to set that header, not so much for a client.

Comment: @RenanAngeliniFerrari also do not forget that http.Request has a [RemoteAddr](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/?#Request.RemoteAddr) field, if I'm not mistaken it is not guaranteed that it will contain a value, but if you're not gonna use a proxy, this might be your best bet.

Comment: Thank you for your help. With this information I can already make a decision of what to do. Thank you very much. @mkopriva